Reset Azure Functions Sequence Number
I am working with Azure Functions where another team is in charge of the consumer hub. Since this is still in development and I am new, I have been able to get some events.
Unfortunately, I am in a situation where I get the following error:
 System.Private.CoreLib: The supplied sequence number '969' is invalid. The last sequence number in the system is '893'
I am aware of what the error means, however I do not know how to reset it, as I would like it to start the sqequence number from 1.
I was told to use Azurerite and delete some files, but I am not sure which files are being referred to.
My local.settings.json files has the following settings
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
Can someone please direct me in the right place.
I tried deleting some files but there was no change.

Can you share your code in the question?

I managed to figure out how to reset it. I had to install Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer which can be downloaded on this link.
Once the application is downloaded and installed, you'll need to sign in using your Azure subscription. Once signed in, then the subscription will open. This will give you the option to see the blob containers.

On the blob containers, you'll find the containers. Deleting them will start the sequences from scratch.
Hope it helps someone.
